# How can I find the relics for the Archaeology 101 achievement?

Tags: far-cry-3

The achievement states to find a total of 60 relics... Is there a way to track those relics in game, or is there a map to do it?

Comment: I surmise that the neg votes are for the original edit. The question as it currently stands does not seem to violate any rules...

Comment: Downvotes don't have anything to do with rules violations. Question closure votes have to do with rules violations. Downvotes can be for pretty much anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 120 relics in total.
You can buy a map with their location at the weapons dealer.
You will be able to apply a filter for the relics specifically.

Comment: Ah thank you.  As with my other question posts, I didn't know there was the ability to purchase a map for them.  This is super easy.